# Error using xadmin

Tags: python, django

This is my registered xadmin APP

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'courses',
    'operation',
    'organization',
    'xadmin',
    'crispy_forms'
]
```

This is the urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
import xadmin

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^xadmin/', xadmin.site.urls),
]
```

But I don't know what to do with this problem, I just started to learn django

```
  File "C:\Users\PC_LF\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\xadmin\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from xadmin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "C:\Users\PC_LF\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\xadmin\sites.py", line 3, in <module>
    from future.utils import iteritems
ImportError: No module named 'future'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will resove you problem

```
pip install django-import-export
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have already created the environment of py2. X to solve this problem, and now I can continue to write django on py3. X

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if xadmin requires [python-future](http://python-future.org/index.html). You can install it with:

```
pip install python-future
```

Answer (score 1):

in your urls.py do something like...

```
from django.conf.urls import url,patterns
from django.contrib import admin
import xadmin
xadmin.autodiscover()

from xadmin.plugins import xversion
xversion.register_models()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'xadmin/', include(xadmin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: According to what you said, the exception was resolved, but the module that this exception says is shipped in xadmin. Why is it wrong   
  File "C:\Users\PC_LF\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\xadmin\plugins\importexport.py", line 48, in <module>
    from import_export.admin import DEFAULT_FORMATS, SKIP_ADMIN_LOG, TMP_STORAGE_CLASS
ImportError: No module named 'import_export'